# DR Racket Flip a list of letter

Tags: scheme, racket

this is a recursive function flip in Scheme which accepts a list of atoms of arbitrary length as its only argument and returns that list with adjacent elements flipped. In other words, the
function alternates elements of a list (i.e., given a list [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6...,an] as an argument,
produce [a2,a1,a4,a3,a6,a5,...]). If n is odd, an remains at the end of the resulting list.  not using any auxiliary functions.

here is my sample

```
> (flip '())
()

> (flip '(a))
(a)

> (flip '(a b))
(b a)

> (flip '(a b c d))
(b a d c)

> (flip '(a b c d e))
(b a d c e)
```

Comment: Ok, so there's a homework assignment here.  What do you have problems with?

Answer (score 2):

This is homework, so I can't give you a straight answer. Here's the general idea of the solution, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (flip lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)                   ; The list is empty:
         <???>)                        ; return the empty list.
        ((null? (cdr lst))             ; The list has a single element:
         <???>)                        ; return a list with the single element.
        (else                          ; The list has at least two elements:
         (cons <???>                   ; cons the second element ...
               (cons <???>             ; ... to the first element ...
                     (flip <???>)))))) ; ... and advance two elements at once.
```

Answer (score 0):

(define (flip lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         null)
        ((null? (cdr lst))
         lst)
        (else
         (cons (car (cdr lst))
               (cons (car lst)
                     (flip (cdr (cdr lst))))))))